# How to receive current list of Rails initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails Guides say [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initializers): "Below is a comprehensive list of all the initializers found in Rails". But how can I receive such list?

I.e if I have `MyApp`, I want to find some method `MyApp::Application.initializers` (just example, not works), that returns me full used initializers list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I find it!

It is `MyApp::Application.instance.initializers`

Comment: Or you can use `Rails.application.initializers`